# Is it ok to await a collection of 1000 tasks in a .NET app? Or should batching be used?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await

I have a simple console app testing out some code.

My code has a list of 1000 numbers and putting each number/int onto an Azure Queue.

Now, I do this asyncronously and it's works great. here's my code from my library:

```
var tasks = stagedFileIds.Select(stagedFileId => QueueFileToProcessAsync(stagedFileId));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
          .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Works great.

But .. is this a bad thing? should I batch this into 50's or 25's or something? But most importantly ... batch it?

What is 'the cost' of doing the above code?

Remember, this is a console app *right now*. I'm going to move this to an Azure Function at some point.

Comment: It is already batched on the threadpool. It doesn't start 1000 threads.

Comment: It probably depends on what these tasks do. If you wrap threads in tasks you have just spawned a 1000 threads, that's not good. If you wrap asynchronous I/O in tasks, you might've kicked off 1000 requests to a remote server, that is probably not good either. If you've queued up 1000 tasks that will use asynchronous I/O and run its code using the threadpool, perhaps it's all good. But the code in the question is neither good or bad in this respect. This is how you await 1000 tasks, it's the tasks that might be the problem, not this code.

Comment: You'd get better performance and manageability if you used ActionBlock with a DOP>1. As for Azure Functions - adding 3-4 orders of magnitude of latency isn't going to improve things. Right now the latencey from moving to one task to another, or one block to another is negligible. *Plus* TPL Dataflow and TPL itself offers easy buffering and throttling. That's *not* trivial with any serverless platform

Comment: In any case, a TPL Dataflow pipeline is closer to a pipeline of Azure Functions. Each TransformBlock to the pipeline can become a separate function

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *awaiting* lots of tasks. I did stress testing on `WhenAll` (using asynchronous tasks) years ago and was impressed - you hit memory issues sooner than you'll ever hit the `WhenAll` limitation ([which is over 2 billion tasks](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5620)). Much better than the `64` of the old wait-for-multiple-handles API. However, you can consider throttling your *requests* - [a queue can handle 2000/sec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).

Answer (score 2):

You should throttle them in a asynchronous way, to make sure you are not making too many QueueFileToProcessAsync operations in parallel, unless you are sure it is harmless. I recommend you [Stephen Cleary introduction to TPL Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html), where [part 3](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/10/introduction-to-dataflow-part-3.html) and his other post [Async Producer/Consumer Queue using Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html) addresses throttling.

If you are calling and endpoint you will be throttled probably by the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` as @Gerino pointed out.

Just for the craic, if you had to implement this yourself without TPL Dataflow, you can do it with the [.NET Concurrent Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// prototype code
static class TaskThrottlingExtension
{
    public static async Task ThrottleProcessingAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inputs, int parallel, Func<T, Task> process)
    {
        var queues = new BlockingCollection<T>[parallel];
        var tasks = new Task[parallel];
        for (int i = 0; i < parallel; i++)
        {
            var queue = queues[i] = new BlockingCollection<T>(1);
            tasks[i] = Task.Run( async () =>
            {
                foreach (var input in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    await process(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            });
        }

        try
        {
            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {
                BlockingCollection<T>.AddToAny(queues, input);
            }

            foreach (var queue in queues)
            {
                queue.CompleteAdding();
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var queue in queues)
            {
                queue.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your operations are IO-blocked, meaning they await for some resource, be it access to a file, a web request to return etc., then this is an OK solution (though be wary of exceptions). Whether you should or should not batch it is resource dependent. If all tasks want to write to the same file, then it makes no sense to async it at all. If all tasks write to the same drive - well, it might be ok. If you call an external web-server, it depends how many requests it can handle (and read about `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`)

If your operations are CPU-blocked, meaning they require to perform some heavy calculations, data processing on the local machine, then better way to do is a `Parallel.ForEach`. This will automatically take a collection and divide the work between a specific amount of threads (which you can specify using `DegreesOfParallelism` option). If you have 4 HT cores, so 8 logical threads, you can set DOP to 8, and all of your CPU will be fully used to finish processing ASAP. The method will return when all items are done (or you cancelled it with a `CancellationToken`).

Comment: You haven't understood the question well, check comment by @Lasse, as he has mentioned the potential issue with tasks being queued, depending on what they accomplish. This is not about Async-Await Vs Parallel. Also the option of TPL data flow suggested by Panagiotis